# Finding out what user Apache is running as in windows?

Tags: apache

I am new to Windows and I am trying to figure out what user Apache is running on.  In Linux I had a simple command `ps aux | grep apache`.  How do I  find that out in windows?  Is it some where in httpd.conf file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default the Apache services are registered to run as the system  user (the LocalSystem account).

The section "Running Apache as a Service" in the help documentation below might help you configure Apache the way that you want to.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/platform/windows.html

Answer (score 14):

You can include a line of code in your PHP script:

```
echo exec('whoami');
```

Answer (score 9):

1. Bring up the task manager by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.
2. Go to the Processes tab and sort by Image Name. In Server 2012, go to the Details tab and sort by Name.
3. Look for apache.exe (or httpd.exe) and check the User Name column.

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell you can interrogate the registry for the user context the service is running under:

```
(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\system\CurrentControlSet\Services\Apache2.4).ObjectName
```