# PHP (WAMP) + shell_exec + powershell + excel macro can not work

Tags: excel, powershell, wamp, shell-exec

I call a power shell script from php with `shell_exec`

Power shell script opens an excel workbook and runs a `macro`:

```
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path e:\dt\surgicare\something.xlsm
$app = $excel.Application
$workbook = $app.workbooks.open($excelfiles)
$app.Visible = $false
$workbook.Activate()
$app.Run("surgicare_frissites")
$workbook.close($false)
$excel.quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($app)
Remove-Variable app
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
Remove-Variable excel
```

It can run ps script, but it returns error.
I can read in `"wamp/logs/php_error.log"` that Microsoft Excel cannot open `something.xlsm`.

The same error is in `"wamp/logs/apache_error.log"`

If I run `power-shell` script manually it works fine, there is no error, macro does what it has to do.

Any idea? What did I miss?

Comment: When you run the script via PHP are you sure it's running under the same user account as when you run it manually?  Is "E:" a mapped drive?

Comment: E: is not a mapped drive. I'm not sure it is the same user account or not. How can I check it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289133/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as-in-windows

Comment: User account is the same in both case. Any other idea?

Comment: Sorry -no other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

**Win7x64, PHP 8.0 (XAMPP), Excel 16, in PHP ini add extension=php_com_dotnet.dll**

```
<?php
// starting Excel
$objExcel = new com("excel.application") or die("Unable to instantiate objExcel");
echo "Loaded objExcel, version {$objExcel->Version}\n";

//closing objExcel
$objExcel->Quit();

//free the object
$objExcel = null;
?>
```

And I see in Firefox: Loaded objExcel, version 16.0